# Random block design ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova, experiment-design, blocking

Quick question: I have found [this tutorial](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/analysis-variance/randomized-block-design) which recommends a two-factorial design for the following setup: three menu items (fixed factor) are tested in six restaurants (random factor). The guide recommends using

```
aov( response ~ item + restaurant )
```

I think that the correct way of doing that would be

```
aov( response ~ item + Error( restaurant / item ) )
```

I am confused.

**My question: am I right, or am I wrong and the author of the tutorial is right?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks right to me! There's a really good tutorial that I use in teaching R courses Baron's [Using R for Psychology Experiments](http://www.psych.upenn.edu/~baron/rpsych.pdf). Even if you're not doing psych. experiments, I think they way Baron does a great job explaining ANOVA and the proper use of the `Error()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just note

```
aov( response ~ item + restaurant )
```

gives the same Anova (same DF and sums of squares for restaurant, item and residuals, so same F test) as

```
aov( response ~ item + Error( restaurant / item ) )
```